# Dynamically adding an object?

Tags: c++

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

static int c;

class DAI   //DynamicArrayInput
{
public :
    void getCountry()
    {
    cout << "Country : ";
    cin >> Country;
    }

    void putCountry()
    {
    cout << Country << endl;
    }
    static int putCount()
    {
    return count;
    }
private :
    static int count;
    char Country[30];
};



int main()
{
vector< DAI > A;
DAI B[3];
//DAI * B;

cout << "Enter name of countries\n";
  for(int i=0; i < 3; i++)
  {
        //THIS DOESN'T WORK
    /*
    c++;   //c is a static variable declared at top
    B = new DAI[sizeof(DAI) * c/sizeof(DAI)];
    GIVES WRONG OUTPUT :
    Enter name of countries
    Country : a
    Country : b
    Country : c
    Printing name of countries


    c
    size of vector A is 3
    vector after initialisation:

    */  
    A.push_back(B[i]);
    B[i].getCountry(); 
  }
  cout << "Printing name of countries\n";
  for(int i=0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    B[i].putCountry();
  }

cout << "size of vector A is " << A.size() << "\
    \nvector after initialisation:" << endl;

return 0;
}


**/*
CORRECT OUTPUT WITH LIMITED ARRAY SIZE = 3:
*Enter name of countries
 Country : a
 Country : b
 Country : c
 Printing name of countries
 a
 b
 c
 size of vector A is 3
 vector after initialisation:*
*/**
```

I am just learning and this is not my homework,
I dont want to be limited to any array size such as above but when i try to use the staements in the first for loop as mentioned it does not work
i mean this does not works

```
c++;   //c is a static variable declared at top
B = new DAI[sizeof(DAI) * c/sizeof(DAI)];  //B is a pointer of type class DAI
```

My aim is to use arrays of objects i like dynamically so that i can input any number of countries I don't want to use something like B[3] with something known array size but i am unable to do.

Please guide me, help me.

Comment: Use an `std::vector` or `std::deque`, which are auto-resizing containers. I see you are holding arrays in a vector - you could already have `std::vector<std::vector<DAI> >`.

Comment: Well I have used it in the program but Unable to proceed with it see first line of main

Comment: You don't initialize c anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> c++;   //c is a static variable declared at top
>   B = new DAI[sizeof(DAI) * c/sizeof(DAI)];

Here you are confusing `new` with `malloc`. To allocate c elements of type DAI, just do

```
B = new DAI[c];
```

However, your best bet is to stay with std::vector, which handles size and capacity itself.

```
for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
    A.push_back(DAI());
```

adds 10 DAIs to the vector A.

**Edit**
You can also create the vector with a number of DAIs from the start:

```
std::vector<DAI> A(10);
```

This also creates a vector with 10 elements, all at once. Unlike `B[3]`, which always contains 3 elements, the vector can grow or shrink as needed without you having to handle the allocations.

Comment: very nice! Thanks, Bo I will try B = new DAI[c] I dont get the second one DAI()

Comment: yes, your second idea works ...thanks  a lot but whats DAI() is it a constructor call how does this works

Comment: Yes, it is a constructor creating new DAIs to be added to the vector. I also added a new example to my answer on how to create the vector **with elements**, without using  a loop.

Comment: Thanks,I will accept your answer because I can accept only one at a time even though I haven't tried to implement the answer given below by Julio his answer also seems reasonable to me.

Answer (score 0):

Your array is static `DAI[3] v` (v is in the process' stack). To be able to add an element dynamically, you need to change it with `DAI[INITIAL_SZ] v = new DAI[INITIAL_SZ]` (now v is in the heap) so that now you can realloc it when adding/deleting elements.